# Better Way to Check if Values are in a List?

Tags: python, list, loops, optimization

I have the following code which runs through a list of words and increments variables representing colors as follows:

```py
  white = 0
  gold = 0
  silver = 0
  grey = 0
  lavender = 0
  pink = 0
  red = 0
  green = 0
  blue = 0
  #list of colors
  colors = ['white','gold','silver','grey','lavender','pink','red','green','blue']
  #increment color variables accordingly
  for i in wordList:
    if colors[0] in i:
      white+=1
    if colors[1] in i:
      gold+=1
    if colors[2] in i:
      silver+=1
    if colors[3] in i:
      grey+=1
    if colors[4] in i:
      lavender+=1
    if colors[5] in i:
      pink+=1
    if i == colors[6]:
      red+=1
    if colors[7] in i:
      green+=1
    if colors[8] in i:
      blue+=1
```

I feel like there must be a better way to do this, but I'm not sure what it is.
Thanks.

Comment: Hold the variables whose names are colours in a `dict`: `{'white': 0, 'gold': 0, ...}`. Then use a second for loop to check each key in the list and increment the value by 1.

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you are looking for is [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html).
which returns a dictionary with the name and number occurrences

```
from collections import Counter
d = Counter(wordList)
```

Now d will have what you are looking for and you can iterate over it doing d.items() or just d.values()

Answer (score 1):

Python contains the best datastructure for this issue called `Counter`

```
import collections
colors = ['white','gold','silver','grey','lavender','pink','red','green','blue']
counter = collections.Counter(colors)
print(counter)
```

The result

```
Counter({'white': 1, 'gold': 1, 'silver': 1, 'grey': 1, 'lavender': 1, 'pink': 1, 'red': 1, 'green': 1, 'blue': 1})
```

And you may access to the elements by names

```
> counter['white']
1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [defaultdicts](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=defaultdict#collections.defaultdict) for it:

```
from collections import defaultdict
colors_dict = defaultdict(int)
colors = ['white','gold','silver','grey','lavender','pink','red','green','blue']
wordList = ['lavender','gold','silver','waka','lavender','lavender']
for word in wordList:
    if word in colors:
        colors_dict[word] += 1
print(colors_dict)
```

> `defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'silver': 1, 'lavender': 3, 'gold': 1})`